# Discord.py CheckError every time check is false

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Whenever a check returns false, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command checkme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ade/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ade/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/ade/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 744, in prepare
    raise CheckFailure('The check functions for command {0.qualified_name} failed.'.format(self))
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command checkme failed.
```

Even with a check where its clearly not some other error with the check, such as this basic always-false command, I get the error. While it doesn't actually disturb the code, I was hoping to get a clean console that information/real errors could be printed to, and that wouldnt be clogged with this error. Is there a way to not raise this error?

```
def returnfalse(ctx):
    return False

@bot.command(name='testcommand')
@commands.check(returnfalse)
def testcommand(ctx):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to have the check failure dismissed every time, I would suggest setting up an `on_command_error` event.
In the main file:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CheckFailure):
        pass
    else:
        print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)
```

Be sure to import `traceback` and `sys`. You will get every other error as intended, put the CheckFailure will be passed. If you remove the `print` and `traceback` from the `else` statement, the `on_command_error` will eat all of your errors.